Crystal Reports Error: "Missing Parameter Values" in C# Code
I'm working on a C# (version 5) project where I need to generate a PDF report using Crystal Reports and a PostgreSQL database. I have a stored procedure that takes one input parameter (refno), and I'm able to successfully retrieve data into a DataTable and DataSet. However, when I try to generate the report, I keep encountering the error: "Missing parameter values".
    public void GenerateAck(string refno)
{
    using (IDataStore dataStore = DataStores.NewEGWBillDS)
    {
        DSTransaction trans = dataStore.BeginTransaction();
        DataTable dt_ack = new DataTable("S_P_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT");
        DataSet M_Ds = new DataSet();
        DataStores.NewEGWBillDS.FillDataTable(new SP_S_P_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT() { AppNo = refno }, dt_ack);

        M_Ds.Tables.Add(dt_ack);

        if (M_Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string fileName = refno + "_ACK_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".pdf";
            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocPath"].ToString();
            string w_path = "NSC\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");

            if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\" + w_path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\" + w_path);

            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Reports\\rpt_AppAck_Receipt.rpt"));
            cryRpt.SetDataSource(M_Ds.Tables[0]);

            cryRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, path + "\\" + w_path + "\\" + fileName);
            cryRpt.Close();
            cryRpt.Dispose();

            // Some other code for logging and displaying the generated PDF
        }
    }
}

I have tried so many suggestion from internet but not getting a proper solution for that, Please if anyone have solution for this please guide me.

It sounds like the report rpt_AppAck_Receipt.rpt has its own parameters.
If any of them are required you have 2 options

pass-in a value for that parameter
modify the report so all parameters have a default values (probably not what you want)

This S/O question has some nice sample code for passing-in a parameter c# passing parameters to crystal reports error "Missing Parameter Values"
